# Update WSL Ubuntu Terminal, When Windows updates?

Tags: visual-studio-code, settings, windows-subsystem-for-linux, windows-terminal

My terminal is not behaving like it should. For some reason my Ubuntu terminal doesn't seem to be connected. I have my machine setup for school and our coding environment and it got disturbed. I don't know if it was a extension that did it or a update. I tried to turn off my updates on window to keep from doing this for right now and it happen. I have WSL Ubuntu terminal setup. I recently add GitHub copilot and gitlens and I don't know if those could of have done it too.

I tried to re-connect to it several times, when I open my terminal it says the terminal behavor can be configured in advance profile settings. then in the actual terminal it says in [process exit with code 4294967295 (0xffffffff)], I just a new student and I don't know what happen.

Comment: what's with the vscode tag here? Are you using VS Code's integrated terminal? Or is this in the the GNOME terminal application that comes with Ubuntu?

Comment: I have WSL Ubuntu and yes it is integrated with my VS code.

Comment: it's pretty much Ubuntu running in my windows Power shell. I can switch back and forth from the shell to Ubuntu.

Comment: I can take a screen shot of my terminal, so you can see what I'm talking about

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have Windows and WSL OS on my computer. WSL is Windows Subsystem for Linux. The Windows Subsystem for Linux lets developers run a GNU/Linux environment-including most command-line tools, utilities, and applicants- directly on Windows, unmodified, without the overhead of a traditional virtual machine or dual boot. It runs pretty much in my Terminal as well as Power Shell. It's a Shell terminal too.

Comment: Please, only need people who know what they are talking about too. please don't waste my time. A lot of people on here should know what I'm talking about when I say Ubuntu WSL, It's not wanting to connect at all.

Answer (score 0):

This error code is usually related to network issues, though some other things, like a corrupted virtual disk also can cause this, in this case you're probably better off reinstalling.

[This topic](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/5092) proposes loads of workarounds, but I've filtered some out which helped me out sometime or looked the most promising.

- Shutdown your whole WSL environment. You can do this by rebooting your PC or running `wsl --shutdown` in a terminal window (i.e. a cmd or Powershell window)
- If above does not work, open an **elevated** terminal (Choose `Run as Administrator` when right-clicking on the Terminal) and run `netsh winsock reset`
- Shutdown any Docker servers running on your host OS as they can apparently interfere with DNS traffic, and prevent WSL from booting.

I don't know how you fire up your WSL, but if the above steps don't work, try booting from within a command line using the `wsl` command.

Comment: I got it. What had happened was that my windows updated and The Terminal didn't. So I had to update the Terminal by typing in the command line in Windows Power Shell this wsl.exe --update. Then I was able to connect back with Ubuntu WSL.

Answer (score 0):

So I found the answer to my problem and wanted to share it with others that may have a similar problem to my problem. The problem was that my Windows updated but my terminal didn't at all. To fix the problem you have to update the terminal as well. Go to the Terminal, much sure you are in windows power shell, and the command line type wsl.exe --update. Then exit out of all windows and then re-open your terminal.